# How to export dx-data-grid (with filters) to XtraReport PDF

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtrareport, devextreme-angular

I'm trying to export a dx-data-grid with filters to PDF. Since DevExtreme does not have built-in functionality for this yet, I need a workaround. I would like to use DevExpress XtraReport to generate the report.
The problem is I'm not sure how to send the grid datasource to XtraReport and have the XtraReport use it to create the report.

In my Angular component I get the datasource with filters applied and then try to post the data to my web api controller.

```
let gridDataSource = this.dataGrid.instance.getDataSource();

gridDataSource.items() <- Json array of items

this.dataService.PostData(gridDataSource.items());
```

Data Service

```
 public PostData(model: data[]): Observable<any> 
 {
        return this.httpClient.post<any>(GlobalVariable.BASE_API_URL + `DataExport`, model.values, {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            })
        });
    }
```

This does not seem to work.

If anyone has links to an example of exporting grid data to PDF that makes use of XtraReports I would appreciate that too.